# display the even numbers from 1 to 500 using a while loop and the break keyword in swift

Tags: swift, loops, while-loop, control-flow

My question is as on the title.  I'm trying to print even numbers from 1 to 500 suing a while loop and break keyword.  Below is my best possible answer I can think of, but this only print number 2.  I've been spending hours but I wasn't able to solve it.

```
var number = 0

while true{
    number += 2 
    print(number)

    if number % 2 == 0 && number <= 500 {
    break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Stride](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641347-stride)

```
for evenNumber in stride(from: 0, through: 500, by: 2) {
    print(evenNumber)
}
```

To specifically do this with while and break:

```
var i = 0
while true {
    print(i)
    i += 2
    if i > 500 {
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: except `0` is not in 1 to 500

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in 0...500 {
    if i % 2 == 0 {
        print(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: If there won't be any `else` it may be beneficial to move condition in `where` clause (`for i in 0...500 where i%2 == 0`),

Answer (score 2):

**Use below code**

```
var numbers = 0...500
for number in numbers {
    if number % 2 == 0 {
        print(number)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier to use build-in `stride`

```
let arr = Array(stride(from: 0, to: 502, by: 2))       
print(arr)
```

//
For manually

```
var counter = 0
var arr = [Int]()
while counter <= 500 {
 if counter % 2 == 0 {
      print(counter)
      arr.append(counter)
  }
     counter += 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var number = 0

while true {
    number += 2
    print(number)
    // ↓ Your code goes here ↓
    if number > 499 {
        break
    }
}
```